# Screen artifact stuck in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

For some reason, I can't get rid of this screen artifact on my Windows 10 machine. All GPU drivers are the latest from Intel.

[image]

I have tried:

1. Resizing desktop resolution
2. Refreshing desktop
3. Locking and unlocking the screen
4. Restarting windows graphics driver

Everything short of reboot doesn't work, any other options?

Comment: Something to try : Open Task Manager, find Windows Explorer in Windows processes, right-click and restart.  If this works, I can make it an Answer.

Comment: If you don't mind not getting reminders of updates from this notification app, you can disable the app itself.  Some of them are present in Task Manager Startup tab, some of them have Settings to start when you log in or when Windows starts, and some have to be uninstalled in order to be rid of them.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage It didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up closing the Intel driver program and it turns out the notification went away that was stuck in the background somehow.